# What does "tar -cvf /dev/nst0 /home/user1 >> file1.log" do?

Tags: bash, tar

I need help to understand the following command.

```
tar -cvf /dev/nst0 /home/user1 >> file1.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the man page :

```
-c stands for create
-v is for verbose
-f specify the archive name
```

And `tar -cvf` is equivalent to `tar -c -v -f`, so what this is doing is creating an archive of  `/home/user1` into `/dev/nst0`. The `>> file1.log` is redirecting and appending the standard output to file1.log.
`tar -cvf archive_name [files] > file.log` would erase any existing content in file1.log

Have a look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#IOREDIRREF) for an explanation on I/O redirection

Answer (score 1):

In addition to shodanex's answer: this creates a tar archive, written to /dev/nst0 (a tape drive?) from /home/user1 and appends the output (remember verbose -v) to file1.log